# Prove that $R[x] \cong R[y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

How do I prove that $R[x] \cong R[y]$? I understand that $R[n]$ represents the set of all polynomials in $n$ with coefficients from the commutative ring $R$, but I don't know how to even start this problem.

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I will outline an sketch for how you might start thinking about this problem. First, recall that two sets are isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism between the two sets. Consider a polynomial in $R[x]$. How could you map this to $R[y]$? Then show that this mapping is well-defined, injective, surjective, and operation-preserving. Then, you have your explicit isomorphism, so you can say that $R[x]\cong R[y]$.

Comment: Is it just $f(x)=y$?

Comment: That map is neither injective, nor surjective, nor operation-preserving. (Also, you do not generally denote mapping with an equal sign.) Try $f(x)\mapsto f(y)$. You can do the property verification on your own.